# React update component after API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am fairly new to React and I am having trouble with some async code. I am trying to make a call to my server for price information between two different locations. The server returns the price information and I set it to the variable rides. I then have a component to display the prices. The problem is the price that is being rendered is the default price that I set it ($0). I'm pretty sure I need to do something with useEffect but I don't know where to put it.

I am first calling to Google for route information and then calling to fetchPrice() to get the pricing information from my server

```
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
import React from "react";

import Places from "./places";
import Rides from "./rides";
import Payment from "./payment";
import { ScreenTypes } from "../enums/screenTypes.ts";
import { RideTypes } from "../enums/rideTypes.ts";

type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
type DirectionsResult = google.maps.DirectionsResult;
type MapOptions = google.maps.MapOptions;


// Map Component
export default function Map() {

  //***VARIABLES*** 
  //Keeps track of what screen we are on
  const [currentScreen, setCurrentScreen] = useState(ScreenTypes.LocationScreen)

  //The ride variables
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(RideTypes.Sedan)
  const rides = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Sedan', price: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Minivan', price: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Full Size SUV', price: 0 },
  ];

  //Location related variables
  const [pickupLocation, setPickupLocation] = useState<LatLngLiteral>();
  const [dropoffLocation, setDropoffLocation] = useState<LatLngLiteral>();
  const [directions, setDirections] = useState<DirectionsResult>();
  const mapRef = useRef<GoogleMap>();
  const center = useMemo<LatLngLiteral>(() => ({ lat: 44, lng: -80 }), [])
  const options = useMemo<MapOptions>(() => ({
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    clickableIcons: false
  }), [])
  const onLoad = useCallback((map) => (mapRef.current = map), []);
  const [searchDisabled, setSearchDisabled] = useState(true);


  //***FUNCTIONS***
  //Get directions from Google Directions API
  const fetchDirections = () => {
    console.log("We Entered fetchDirections.")
    if (!pickupLocation && !dropoffLocation) {
      console.log("Exiting because locations aren't set")
      return
    }

    const service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    service.route(
      {
        origin: pickupLocation,
        destination: dropoffLocation,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === "OK" && result) {
          setDirections(result);
          const test = async () => {
            console.log("We entered test")
            if (await fetchPrice()==true){
              setCurrentScreen(ScreenTypes.RidesScreen);
            }
          }
          test();
        }
      }
    )
  }

  //Get prices for the trip from server
  const fetchPrice = async () => {
    console.log("Started fetchPrice function");
    const URL = "myServerUrlThatImNotShowingStackoverflow";

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(URL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // Add other headers if needed
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "from": {
              "latitude": pickupLocation?.lat,//26.336556,
              "longitude": pickupLocation?.lng//-81.436839
            },
            "to": {
              "latitude": dropoffLocation?.lat,//26.140444,
              "longitude": dropoffLocation?.lng//-81.791761
            }
          }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json.priceSedan, json.priceMinivan, json.priceFullSizeSuv);
        rides[0].price = json.priceSedan;
        rides[1].price = json.priceMinivan;
        rides[2].price = json.priceFullSizeSuv;
        console.log("This is what rides is equal to before we return ->", rides)

        return true;

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return fetchData();
  };
  


  //UI
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {((currentScreen == ScreenTypes.LocationScreen)||(currentScreen == ScreenTypes.RidesScreen)) && 
        <div className="controls">
            <div className="outlined">
              <div className="location-search">
                <h2>Request a ride</h2>
                <Places
                  setLocation={(position) => {
                    setPickupLocation(position);
                    if (dropoffLocation) {
                      setSearchDisabled(false)
                    } else {
                      mapRef.current?.panTo(position);
                    }
                  }}
                />
                <Places
                  setLocation={(position) => {
                    setDropoffLocation(position);
                    if (pickupLocation) {
                      setSearchDisabled(false)
                    } else {
                      mapRef.current?.panTo(position);
                    }
                  }}
                />
                <input
                  type="datetime-local"
                  className="pickup-time"
                  name="pickup-time" />
                <button disabled={searchDisabled} onClick={fetchDirections}>Search</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      }
      {(currentScreen == ScreenTypes.RidesScreen) && <Rides selectedOption={selectedOption} setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption} setCurrentScreen={setCurrentScreen} rides={rides} />}
      
      {(currentScreen == ScreenTypes.CheckoutScreen) && <Payment />}

      <div className="map">
        <GoogleMap
          zoom={10}
          center={center}
          mapContainerClassName='map-container'
          options={options}
          onLoad={onLoad}
        >
          {directions
            ? <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />
            : (pickupLocation)
              ? <Marker position={pickupLocation} />
              : dropoffLocation && <Marker position={dropoffLocation} />
          }
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Rides component where I display the ride details that I get back from the server...

```
import React from "react";
import '../styles/rides.css';
import { RideTypes } from "../enums/rideTypes.ts";
import { ScreenTypes } from "../enums/screenTypes.ts";


export default function Rides({ selectedOption, setSelectedOption, setCurrentScreen, rides }) {
  
  return (
    <div className="ride-options-column">
      {rides.map((ride) => (
        <Ride key={ride.id} ride={ride} selectedOption={selectedOption} setSelectedOption={setSelectedOption} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentScreen(ScreenTypes.CheckoutScreen)}>Go to checkout here</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Ride({ ride, selectedOption, setSelectedOption }) {
    const myOption : RideTypes = ride.name
    const handleSelect = () => {
        setSelectedOption(myOption);
    };

    return (
        <div className="ride-option">
        <img src="../src/assets/Example_Car.png" alt="Car" />
        <h1>{ride.name}</h1>
        <p>${ride.price}.00</p>
        <button onClick={handleSelect}>Select</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: There are various things you can try (1) set Rides value by using UseState hook (2) You can also explore React Query (3) call fetchPrice inside useEffect(). (4) console log value of ride in the component where you are displaying value and see if it has correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

When you’re setting the prices for the rides, the Ride component will not re-render with the new prices because it doesn’t know that the rides array has been
updated.

## Solution

```
const [rides, setRides] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'Sedan', price: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Minivan', price: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Full Size SUV', price: 0 },
  ]);

 const json = await response.json();
 setRides((prevRides) =>
    prevRides.map((ride) => ({...ride,
      price: json[`price${ride.name}`],})));
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot to use useState haha

Comment: @JohnCitrowske I'm glad I could help. I have missed too in starting, was looking into await and setCurrentScreen. Don't forget to use `===` at `await fetchPrice()==true`